# ASP.NET Wizard Control inline editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, controls, wizard

I have being developing a form with the wizard control. The final step is a summary of the content that has been entered by the user as a confirmation step before submit the form.

These summary sections also catgorised into visual sections that corresponds with the each WizardSteps.

Each summary section is provided with an edit button that should allow user to edit the content then and there and update the content.

However the form should work without javascript so no use of AJAX. I'm not sure how this can be achieved? Is there a way to assign corresponding WizardStep to a placeholder onClick of the "EDIT" button for that summary section or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i would not bother trying to create a website in asp.net were one specification was that it should have to work without javascript.  It is possible but your options are very limited.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178206.aspx) is a list of controls that don't work without javascript.  I'm afraid wizard is one of them.  If you must not use javascript you are going to have to create your own control that mimics what the wizard does but without JS.